# Is "moving forward" at the end of a sentence grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, participles, dangling-participles

News media talking heads come up with new buzzwords and phrases over time.  One such phrase that has been widely used of late (specifically at the end of a sentence), is: *moving forward*.

For example:

> Economists expect to see significant progress in this area **moving forward**.

Is this correct to say, grammatically speaking?

Comment: It's an old expression, used in various senses and contexts.  The above usage is a bit tenuous, grammar-wise, but not that far "out there".

Comment: I suspect that the author of the cited sentence gets paid by the word. I do not see that "moving forward" adds anything to the meaning.

Comment: That just means “from now on”.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's a synonym for "in the future", so it's an **adjective phrase**.  It modifies 'progress'.

Predicting if and when it will become 'accepted' (and to whom) is beyond our abilities, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi, John. Is there any reason not to see it as an *adverbial phrase* modifying "expect to see"?

Comment: @Rathony Would "in the future" be an adverbial phrase?  I consider the thing that's being modified to be the progress itself -  we expect to see progress moving forward, we expected to see progress in the past - not the *perception* of the progress.  "We expect to see *more clearly* progress in this area..." would be an adverbial phrase.  But I guess it could be argued that way.

Comment: Well, you have a valid point. But I think "moving forward" modifies to "see", not "progress" as in "Economists expect to see significant progress in this area if (when) they move forward (which means *in the future* or *from now on*)." I think it is closer to participial phrase (dangling participle) rather than an adjectival phrase modifying a noun. Others might differ.

Answer (score 1):

As I have heard this phrase used, it has a bit more baggage than just "from now on," or "in the future."

It does mean that, but in addition, it gives a feeling of moving into the future in a *constructive* way.  Similar to "onward and upward."

Comment: It's definitely a phrase with a lot of baggage. Annoying business jargon.

Comment: @tchrist I've heard it used by an administrator of my son's school district.  I have even used it myself when I needed to assert myself but was trying to avoid appearing intimidating or aggressive.  Also, I was communicating with a colleague of the person I had first heard the phrase from.  It didn't help much but I do think that if I had asserted myself in the normal way, with "In the future, please bla-bla," things would have gone even worse.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally unnecessary. It can be eliminated from any sentence without losing any meaning. It's a vogue phrase that people use indiscriminately because other people use it. The future tense says it all.

Comment: Sure, but the OP asked if it is grammatical. The style comment is helpful but doesn't address the actual question.